# What is the best way to manage Player object of SteamVR plugin for Unity3D when change of scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene, steamvr

I am developping an application using the new version of SteamVR plugin (2.2) for unity and i need to navigate between several scene during the game.

I have for all my scenes a Player object coming from the SteamVR plugin handle input and event, who is a singelton dontDestroyOnLoad, and i don't know the best way to handle this object during the change of scene.

There is 3 options in my opinion :

- For all scene a player object is present, but steamVR don't check if an instance already exist so i add this feature to have only one player after scene initialisation.
- The other solution is  to destroy the current instance before loading the new scene but with the new system of event made by Valve in this version i don't know if it's a good way to manage the fact to have only one player at the time, can potentiolly create event conflict (didn't saw yet).
- The last one but not really confident with it is to let 2 player per scene and one of this is the good instance of the singelton class (way more anoying to get the good instance Player, and can i have conflict between them ?)

If someone have some idea or can give me better understood of my conception issue you are welcome :)

Comment: If it already uses `DontDestroyOnLoad` and a Singleton pattern you should also do something like `private void Awake(){ if(Instance){ Destroy(gameObject); }}` but maybe it does this already anyway.

Comment: @derHugo Yeah thought about it and i think i'm gonna do this, it's wierd that Valve forgot to put something like this in there main class

Comment: Have you found a better solution than this, or is this still the only solution?